# Postgres Bulk Collect and Forall Delete

Tags: postgresql

Currently in Oracle I run a procedure monthly to delete some data.  For performance reasons in Oracle I have used `BULK COLLECT` and `FORALL .. DELETE` to perform the deletes.

Anyone know if there is there anything similar in `Postgres`?  Do I need to be concerned about performance if I use the following to delete a lot of data?

```
DELETE FROM sample WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM test);
```

Comment: Use `WHERE EXISTS` not `WHERE IN`. Otherwise, should be fine so long as `sample` isn't the target of any foreign key refs; if it is, you'll need indexes on the referencing ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WHERE EXISTS` not `WHERE IN`.

Otherwise, should be fine so long as sample isn't the target of any foreign key refs. If it is, you'll need indexes on the referencing ends.

For really big deletes on FKs with `ON DELETE CASCADE` it can be preferable to do a join to delete the referring side in a batch, then delete the referred-to side. That helps prevent millions of individual `DELETE` statements having to run for cascade deletes.